# Loading a string line by line and replacing it using a dictionary - Python

Tags: python-3.x, replace

I'm working on replacing a string using a dictionary.

Substituting with a dictionary is easy, but when replacing all words with the same word, the sentence becomes awkward.

So, I tried to read one line at a time and replace it once, but it failed.

```
# A function that randomly replaces a word
def ttc(*arg):
    a = random.choice([*arg])
    return ''.join(a)

text = """
I'm working on replacing a string using a dictionary.

I'm working on replacing a string using a dictionary.

I'm working on replacing a string using a dictionary.
I'm working on replacing a string using a dictionary.

I'm working on replacing a string using a dictionary.
I'm working on replacing a string using a dictionary.

"""
a_dic = {'working': ttc('tttttt', 'yyyyy', 'iiiiii'),
         'using': ttc('qqqq', 'eeeee', 'rrrrrr'),
         'on': ttc('cdcd', 'vvvdvdvv', 'dvd')
         }

new_list = []
pos = -1
for s in text.split("\n"):
    pos += 1
    if s == "":
        new_list.append(s)
    else:
        for key in a_dic.keys():
            s = s.replace(key, a_dic[key])
            if pos == len(a_dic) - 1:
                new_list.append(s)


for d in new_list:
    print(d)
```

When performing random string substitution using a dictionary, can you replace several same words with different words? The result I want is below

```
text = """
I'm tttttt dvd replacing a string eeeee a dictionary.

I'm yyyyy cdcd replacing a string qqqq a dictionary.

I'm tttttt cdcd replacing a string qqqq a dictionary.
I'm tttttt vvvdvdvv replacing a string eeeee a dictionary.

I'm iiiiii cdcd replacing a string rrrrrr a dictionary.
I'm iiiiii vvvdvdvv replacing a string qqqq a dictionary.

"""
```

Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need the `ttc` function since `choice` already choose an element (string) in your list. So you don't need to join the result.

You can set your dictionary values to functions and use them as replacement in `re.sub`:

```
import re

a_dic = {'working': lambda x: random.choice(['tttttt', 'yyyyy', 'iiiiii']),
         'using': lambda x: random.choice(['qqqq', 'eeeee', 'rrrrrr']),
         'on': lambda x: random.choice(['cdcd', 'vvvdvdvv', 'dvd'])
         }

changed_text = text
for k in a_dic:
  changed_text = re.sub(rf'(?<=\W){k}(?=\W)', a_dic[k], changed_text)

print(changed_text)
```

Output:

```
I'm tttttt dvd replacing a string eeeee a dictionary.

I'm yyyyy cdcd replacing a string qqqq a dictionary.

I'm yyyyy cdcd replacing a string qqqq a dictionary.
I'm tttttt vvvdvdvv replacing a string eeeee a dictionary. cdcd

I'm yyyyy dvd replacing a string eeeee a dictionary.
I'm tttttt vvvdvdvv replacing a string qqqq a dictionary.
```

###### Edit:

You can also create a 'meta' function to avoid looping over the dictionary:

```
def replace_fun(match_obj):
  word = match_obj.group(0)
  if word in a_dic:
    return a_dic[word](word)
  else:
    return word

changed_text = re.sub(r'\w+', replace_fun, text)
```

Comment: I''ve added another solution that might be faster but do not support whitespaces/special characters in dictionary keys.